# Testing with PlaySpec and FluentLenium

Tags: playframework, integration-testing

I'm trying to test a web application, Play Framework 2.5, with PlaySpec and FluentLenium
Here is the code for testing the login page:

```
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec

import org.scalatestplus.play._

class IntegrationSpec extends PlaySpec {

    "My Application" should {
        "work within a browser" in {
            running(TestServer(3333), HTMLUNIT) { browser =>
                browser.goTo("http://localhost:3333")
                browser.title mustBe "My Application"

                browser.$("label").first.getText() must equal ("Login")
                browser.$("label", 1).getText() must equal ("Password")
                browser.fill("input").with("myLogin","myPassword")
                //submit("#submit")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a compile error displaying :

```
identifier expected but 'with' found.

    browser.fill("input").with("myLogin","myPassword")
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to say I may have seen this before in some Scala code because with is a keyword. In that case, I think surrounding the word with in backticks like

```
`with`
```

solved that issue. Not sure if that helps you or not.